# Module not found - trying to use react-native and react-native-tts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out while this module is not working. Every time I try to run my code I get the following failed to compile error:

```
./node_modules/react-native-tts/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in 'C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\klementine\node_modules\react-native-tts'
```

I've been trying to find a module to make text to speech work with just feeding a function a simple string instead of using .wav files, that is why I'm trying to use react-native-tts. Otherwise I'm into anyone's suggestions as well.

This is my index.js that initiates the app

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import theme from "./theme"


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And this is my app page

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import React from "react"
import Home from "./Home"
import Two from "./Two"
import Three from "./Three"
import Eat from "./Eat/Eat"
import NativeSpeech from "./NativeSpeech"

function App() {


  return (

    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/Two" component={Two}/>
          <Route path="/Three" component={Three}/>
          <Route path="/Eat" component={Eat}/>
          <Route path="/NativeSpeech" component={NativeSpeech}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is my package where my dependencies are shown:

```
{
  "name": "klementine",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "node": "^16.4.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.64.2",
    "react-native-tts": "^4.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: react-native-tts is a library developed for espacially react-native. react and react-native is not the same. React is made for web, and React Native is made for mobile. However you can also use speak-tts library which is made for web. https://www.npmjs.com/package/speak-tts

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot and helped me switch my focus.!

Answer (score 0):

The error module not found can also occur because of a possible spelling error not gramatically but because of difference in syntax using pip.
For ex:
Error i faced : Module not found speechRecognition
Package i had installed: pip install speechRecognotion and Installed sucessfully
the error was because in the code import, the correct code was import speech_recognition and i had written import speechRecognition ,for obvious reason that i has installed speechRecogntion . Hence try writing a different syntax for your module.